# is there a more idiomatic way to achive these sequential test, in F#

Tags: f#

I have a function (let's call it 'doSomething') that returns:

```
('a * 'b) option
```

and would like to achieve something like this:

```
let testA = doSomething ....
if testA.IsSome then return testA.Value
let testB = doSomething ....
if testB.IsSome then return testB.Value
let testC = doSomething ....
if testC.IsSome then return testC.Value
```

I'm looking for a computation expression, or an equivalent simple syntax, that would keep executing while the results are None, but leave on the first Some result.

Obviously I want to avoid the while if / elif / elif / ... / elif / else pyramid of doom.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433330/avoiding-the-pyramid-of-doom-with-computation-expressions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858643/getting-rid-of-the-pyramid-of-doom-in-f

Comment: @BentTranberg the OrElse builder could solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option (hehhehe) is to chain together some calls from the `Option` module like so:

```
let doSomething doThisOne tup = if doThisOne then Some tup else None

let f () =
    doSomething false (1, 2)
    |> Option.orElseWith (fun () -> doSomething false (2, 3))
    |> Option.orElseWith (fun () -> doSomething true (3, 4))
    |> Option.defaultValue (0, 0)

f () // Evaluates to (3, 4)
```

You *might* be able to use FsToolkit.ErrorHandling and applicative syntax for the `option` CE, but I don't know what a good way to combine results would look like, so I would personally just chain calls like above.

Answer (score 3):

I see it as an idiomatic pipeline:

```
[
  "test01";
  "test02";
  ...
]
(* |> Seq.ofList - unnecessary, as noted in the comments *)
|> Seq.tryPick doSomething (* sequentially calls 'doSomething' with test params and returns the first result of 'Some(x)' *)
```

Comment: Seq.ofList is not nedded, because a list is already a sequence.